# Show call location of a wrapped function - loguru

Tags: python, logging

I want to log all requests my application is sending (requests.get, requests.post, ...). So as not to have boilerplate, I decided to wrap functions in the `requests` module:

```
import functools

from loguru import logger
import requests

def logging_wrap(foo):
    @functools.wraps(foo)
    def _(*args, **kwargs):
        logger.debug(f"Calling {foo.__name__} with args {args} and kwargs {kwargs}")
        return foo(*args, **kwargs)

    return _

requests.get = logging_wrap(requests.get)

requests.get("https://google.com")
```

The problem is that logs refer to the spot in the wrapper (`logger.debug`), and not where the `requests.get` is called. How can I make loguru display correct call location?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`opt()`](https://loguru.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/logger.html#loguru._logger.Logger.opt) method which is specifically designed to handle the case of wrapped functions thanks to the `depth` parameter:

```py
logger.opt(depth=1).debug(f"Calling {foo.__name__} with args {args} and kwargs {kwargs}")
```